# Rectangle drawing doesnt works in some devices

Tags: android, android-canvas

I'm trying to draw the rectangle on the canvas ,it works well in android device MotoC Plus 7.0 but doesn't work in some devices like Xiaome Redmi 8.0.After debugging the code i have found that the invalidate doesn't update the view by calling onDraw method in Xiaome Redmi 8.0 but for Motoc Plus 7.0 the onDraw method is getting invoked.Below is my custom view,can anyone notice what mistake am i doing here:

```
public class CustomImageView extends View {
private Paint mRectPaint;
private int mStartX = 0;
private int mStartY = 0;
private int mEndX = 0;
private int mEndY = 0;
private boolean mDrawRect = false;


private Bitmap mBitmap;
private double scale;

public void invalidate(boolean mDrawRect) {
    this.mDrawRect = mDrawRect;
}

public CustomImageView(final Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public CustomImageView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public CustomImageView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs,
                        final int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init();
}

public void setContent(Bitmap bitmap, List<Point> pointList, boolean mDrawRect) {
    this.mBitmap = bitmap;
    this.mDrawRect = mDrawRect;

    if (pointList != null && pointList.get(0) != null && pointList.get(1) != null)
        setValue(pointList);

    //setWillNotDraw(false);
    invalidate();
}

private void setValue(List<Point> pointList) {
    mStartX = (int) ((int) Math.min(pointList.get(0).x, pointList.get(1).x) * scale);
    mStartY = (int) ((int) Math.min(pointList.get(0).y, pointList.get(1).y) * scale);
    mEndX = (int) ((int) Math.max(pointList.get(1).x, pointList.get(0).x) * scale);
    mEndY = (int) ((int) Math.max(pointList.get(1).y, pointList.get(0).y) * scale);
    Log.e("mStartX,mStartY :: ", mStartX +","+mStartY);
    Log.e("mEndX,mEndY :: ", mEndX +","+mEndY);
}

private void init() {
    mRectPaint = new Paint();
    mRectPaint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#55000000"));
    mRectPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    mRectPaint.setStrokeWidth(5);
    mRectPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    mRectPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mRectPaint.setDither(true);

    //setWillNotDraw(false);

}

@Override
protected void onDraw(final Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    this.scale = drawBitmap(canvas);
    if (mDrawRect) {
        canvas.drawRect(Math.min(mStartX, mEndX), Math.min(mStartY, mEndY),
                Math.max(mEndX, mStartX), Math.max(mEndY, mStartY),
                mRectPaint);
    }
}

private double drawBitmap(Canvas canvas) {
    double viewWidth = canvas.getWidth();
    double viewHeight = canvas.getHeight();
    double imageWidth = mBitmap.getWidth();
    double imageHeight = mBitmap.getHeight();
    double scale = Math.min(viewWidth / imageWidth, viewHeight / imageHeight);

    Rect destBounds = new Rect(0, 0, (int) (imageWidth * scale), (int) (imageHeight * scale));
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, null, destBounds, null);
    return scale;
}

public double getScale() {
    return scale;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved issue by changing the method name

```
 public void invalidate(boolean mDrawRect) {
    this.mDrawRect = mDrawRect;
}
```

to

```
public void invalidateCustomview(boolean mDrawRect) {
    this.mDrawRect = mDrawRect;
}
```